# How can we get city data for search queries from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, geolocation, search-analytics

Is there any way to get  data about the cites in which the search queries were performed from Google Search Console?  The search analytics report shows a list of queries, but I can't figure out which cities they are associated with.

Comment: No, use ad-words keyword finder for search research.

Comment: Simon, any other way we can fetch it?

Comment: No... that information is property of Google and not even Google Adword's will give you the approx numbers.

Comment: What is a "webmaster query"?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Simon had an understanding of the question I was asking about and it was unclear to you. I would like to request, please do not use your credentials and privileges just to make your point right when you are not.

Comment: I edited your question based on what I think you are asking.